# jquery/javascript post to new window when pressing a preview button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have a form with two buttons, submit & preview, the preview button should open a new window with the text from the input areas how do I make that happend?

```
<form method='post'>
//input
<input type='text' name='headline' id='headline' />
<textarea name='content' id='content'></textarea>
//buttons
<input type='submit' id='btnsubmit' value='submit' />
<input type='submit' id='btnpreview' value='preview' />
</form>
```

I can't have target'_blank' in form because i have two buttons, and only one should open in a new window, i would like this to be done in jquery. can someone help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to post the form to a new window, you *need* to set the target of the form. You can set the target for each button:

```
$(function(){
  $('#btnsubmit').click(function(){
    this.form.target = '';
  });
  $('#btnpreview').click(function(){
    this.form.target = '_blank';
  });
});
```

Comment: @ideal: Wow, indeed, I thought the `click` event wasn't fired when pressing Enter on a button. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can onclick change the target of the form:

```
<input type='submit' onclick="this.form.removeAttribute('target')" id='btnsubmit' value='submit' />
<input type='submit' onclick="this.form.setAttribute('target','_blank')" id='btnpreview' value='preview' />
```

But: the problem, I think Marcel likes to point at is:
Once you've clicked on the preview-button, the target is set to _blank. If you now do an [enter] on the `<input>`, the target would'nt be reset to the default-target, it will remain _blank, what's not the desired behaviour.

You can fix this for example that way:

```
<form onsubmit="document.getElementById('btnsubmit').click();return false;">
//input
 <input type='text' name='headline' id='headline' />
 <textarea name='content' id='content'></textarea>
//buttons
 <input type='submit' onclick="this.form.removeAttribute('target');this.form.submit();return false;" id='btnsubmit' value='submit' />
 <input type='submit' onclick="this.form.setAttribute('target','_blank');this.form.submit();return false;" id='btnpreview' value='preview' />
</form>
```

Comment: There really is an issue, it will not always work like expected, see my updated post.