# HTML5 and <frame> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm working on the email blast creator app that allows user to build and send HTML emails. Users can enter some data, select a template from the list, click Preview and see the resulting page inside the current page without refresh. I'm using AJAX POST request to submit the data to the server and get the resulting HTML code - full page with `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags. Before HTML5, I would  insert the resulting page into the `<frame>` tag. for Since  the `<frame>` tag was deprecated in HTML5 how can I display this page inside another? I can't use `<iframe src="/preview..."></iframe>` because I'm using POST and there's no URL that I can use as iframe's src.

Comment: You can't (by definition) make a POST request without a URL

Comment: There is really no significant difference between a frame and an iframe except one goes in a frameset and the other inside a regular document.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Keep the `iframe` blank (with no `src`) until you have a URI to use. Just like you did with your `frame`.</strike>

Create a page with skeletal content:

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and use that as the `iframe`'s initial page. Then you have a `document` on which you may perform your DOM manipulation.

Comment: It's not possible in HTML5 - "...Note that in previous versions of HTML, you could create "fallback content" by placing content within the opening and closing <iframe> </iframe> tags. In HTML 5 however, the code><iframe> element never has fallback content..."

Comment: @Vincent: `<iframe />` is not valid in HTML5? The parameter [looks optional to me](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-src).

Comment: It's valid, but I can't insert anything inside <iframe> ... </iframe> dynamically, it will not display anything, I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [opening a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173082/jquery-javascript-post-to-new-window-when-pressing-a-preview-button)?

Comment: Yes, but it's much nicer not to.

Comment: Not for me as an end-user. I don't like frames one bit.

Comment: I think it's pretty user friendly since it doesn't look like frames at all (no scrollbars, etc.), you see it almost immediately after clicking Preview and you don't have to switch to another window or tab.